# Deleting data grid view rows by clicking button to form2

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, click

I have restaurantSale(form1) and  I have supervisorVoidPass (form2)
the problem is i cant remove the data ..(The system cant find the object)

in my form(1)
is my datagridview.

then
in my form 2 this is my code which this code use for deleting datagridview per row

```
 private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            restaurantSale rs = new restaurantSale();
            string inpPass = "1234";
            if (voidPass.Text == inpPass)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Void Success");
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rs.receiptGrid.SelectedRows)
                {
                    rs.receiptGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
                    rs.ShowDialog();
                    MessageBox.Show("Void Records");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: that is because you create a new form1 from the buttonclick and then you use this new form1 which off course has no data in the datagridview. Do not create a new form1 but use the existing one

Answer (score 2):

this line

```
restaurantSale rs = new restaurantSale();
```

creates a new instance of a form, not the one which is already open (and has some data).

the existing form should be used instead. it can be found in `Application.OpenForms`

```
restaurantSale rs = Application.OpenForms.OfType<restaurantSale>().FirstOrDefault();
if (rs == null) return;
```

it also makes sense to initialize `rs` value *after* password check (`if (voidPass.Text == inpPass)`)